# Unable to add in vagrant package

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, packaging

```
gem@Ubuntu:~/work/source$ ls
package.box  pretty-simple-redismonitor  sonar  Vagrantfile  VirtualBox-4.3.2
gem@Ubuntu:~/work/source$ vagrant package --vagrantfile sonar
/home/gem/work/source/Vagrantfile:5: warning: already initialized constant 
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[default] Creating temporary directory for export...
[default] Exporting VM...
[default] Compressing package to: /home/gem/work/source/package.box
[default] Packaging additional file: sonar
gem@Ubuntu:~/work/source$ vagrant package --vagrantfile pretty-simple-redismonitor
/home/gem/work/source/Vagrantfile:5: warning: already initialized constant 
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[default] Creating temporary directory for export...
[default] Exporting VM...
The specified file to save the package as already exists. 
Please remove this file or specify a different file name for outputting.
```

I am unable to add another item in the package. Actually I am new to vagrant, please let me know how to add and to share these packages with my team members.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add additional files to the packaged box you should use the `--include` option.

Here is the complete usage banner:

```
Usage: vagrant package [vm-name] [--base name] [--output name.box]
                       [--include one,two,three] [--vagrantfile file]

       --base NAME               Name of a VM in virtualbox to package as a base box
       --output NAME             Name of the file to output
       --include x,y,z           Additional files to package with the box.
       --vagrantfile file        Vagrantfile to package with the box.
       -h, --help                Print this help
```

Comment: please let me know like template or eg: because i am new to vagrant and if possible let me know how to share to my team members as well. Thanks in advance